# initializing argument 1 of `int strcmpi(const char*, const char*)' error

Tags: c++

```
char BOOK::retname()
{
    return name;
}
void BOOK::searchbook()
{
    clrscr();
    int flag=0;
    char name2[30];
    FILE *fp;
    cout<<"Enter Book Name: ";
    cin.get();
    gets(name2);
    char name1=retname();
    fp = fopen("Records.txt","rb");
    while(fread(&BOOK,sizeof(BOOK),1,fp)==1){
        if(strcmpi(name1,name2)==0)
            {
                flag=1;
                cout<<"This book is available: ";

    }       }
}
```

I'm getting a few errors here like invalid conversion from char* to char.
  I'm new to file handling questions so debugging is out of my thinking scope.
Please don't butcher me for using gets()
Thank you
PS : char name is private member of class BOOk
  I think I cannot equate string name with a plain char name1 in line14 but I don't know how to fix that.
**EDIT** I'm now getting the error at line 16
"expected primary-expression before ',' token"
   **EDIT** I got it to work, thanks anyways peoples!! Please lock this thread mods

Comment: Read the complete error message, look at the types of the variables you use to call `strcmp`, then learn how to use the C++ standard library and its classes instead of mixing your code with old C constructs.

Comment: Also, never use the old C function `gets`. It has already been removed from the C language, and will soon be removed from the C++ specification as well. Generally, don't mix C++ and C input/output constructs. They are synched by default, but it is confusing.

Comment: `retname()` must return `char*` and you can copy into `char* name1` with   `strcpy(name1,retname())`

Answer (score 1):

Look at the lines of errors you are getting

```
char name1=retname();

if(strcmpi(name1,name2)==0)
```

strcmpi does not take a `char` in, it takes a `char *`.  A char is not a char array.  A char is a single character, so I think you've declared something incorrectly if you have a `char name` variable that is supposed to be longer than one character.

Comment: declaration of char name is ---> char name[30] now it is important because name of book cannot be a single character, what to do now?

Comment: Then name is not a char, it is a char[30], which can be used as a char *.  Your retname function is wrong.  If this is c++, you should be using std::string in any case.

Answer (score 0):

**retname();** function return a **string**, but `name1` variable take only one character because it's declare as a `char`. So, declare `name1` variable `char* name1` or `char name1[]`.

Comment: Yes! I thought of that initially and tried name1[] but doesn't work ! :(